# Creating polygon from DEM raster extent to merge overlapping polygons

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, raster-calculator

I have two elevation rasters split along the Alaska- Canada border.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/174BiQU35RascL7YX58MopJ3vJE0oRXDA/view?usp=sharing
I need to merge them into one product but there is a step along the border where they overlap slightly that I need to smooth out and gdal_merge has no feathering or averaging option for overlapping rasters.
The step is very visible when viewing the contours:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17MnHrZXvmYk3aBihJv6Yjkw5Ov7ao0cW/view?usp=sharing

To solve this I thought to create polygons of each of the rasters so I could clip them and extract the overlapping area then get rasters from each for that area and average them and then merge all those together. To create the polygons I used the raster calculator to get a raster of all one value then use raster to vector to get a polygon. For the US side this worked perfectly well:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/170McIrYFwc2PLZ3UHBoOLC5h-UbeVN97/view?usp=sharing

The CA side not so much:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16y_Gub_yG0vtXihN86RXsPDyjueoPDln/view?usp=sharing . I used the same gdal_calc expression for both, --calc="(A!=-10000)*1". -10000 is the no data value.

Why am I getting this result and is there a better workflow for this problem? I am able to work in ArcGIS or QGIS to solve this but the file sizes are very large(~300 gb) and GDAL is preferable for handling it.

Comment: Converting raster to vector is an *awful* way to merge rasters, especially DEMs.

Comment: Im only doing it so I can isolate the overlapping areas and avg them. If only gdal_merge had this functionality built in